# fscanf doesn't work correctly with string

Tags: c++, string, scanf

I have a simple problem with my application. `fscanf` collects an entire word, but the size (length) is equal to the default size of `currentName`. If the `currentName`'s default length value is lower then the length of a word, the word is cut.

For example:

if `currentName`="123" 
then
`fscanf` will return "Art" instead of "Arthur".

or

if `currentName`="123456789" then `fscanf` will return "Arthur 89" instead of "Arthur".

File "list.txt" contains rows:

```
Arthur 30 1550
Ben 32 2100
Charlie 25 1850
Danny 46 2400
Edward 35 2750
```

What should I change to solve this issue? I have to use fscanf instead of fstream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class Worker
{
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    double salary;
public:
    Worker()
    :name(""),age(99),salary(0)
    {}
    Worker(string name, int age, double salary)
        :name(name),age(age),salary(salary)
    {}
    void showVaulues()
    {
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Name:\t"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Age:\t"<<age<<endl;
        cout<<"Salary:\t"<<salary<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    FILE *myfile=NULL;
    string currentName="123456789";
    int currentAge=0;
    double currentSalary=999999;
    Worker *ptr=NULL;
    myfile=fopen("list.txt","r");
    while (feof(myfile) == 0)
    {
        fscanf(myfile,"%s %d %lf\n",&currentName[0],&currentAge,&currentSalary);
        ptr=new Worker(currentName,currentAge,currentSalary);
        ptr->showVaulues();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C`, when it is clearly `C++`?

Comment: `fscanf(myfile,"%s %d %lf\n",&currentName, ...);`  What compiler are you using?  If it's anything pre C++11, it is undefined behavior to fill a `std::string` like that.  And I am not even so sure it works with C++ 11.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wait, this is legal in C++11?

Comment: I put C tag, because IMO fscanf is closer to C then C++ streams. If it is incorrect, send me PM.

Comment: It works in Visual Studio 2012. I should use fopen_s, but I turned off CRT warnings.

Comment: Please use `<cstdio>` and `<cstdlib>` in `C++`.

Comment: `std::scanf()` can't make strings longer than they already are. All it can do is read data into them.

Comment: @BaummitAugen With all of those darn changes to `std::string` over the past two updates to C++, it's hard to keep track of what is or is not legal vis-a-vis accessing a std::string.  I know for sure that the OP's code produces undefined behavior for C++ 03 and below.

Comment: @st3fan0 The reason that the `C` tag was not warranted is that you're feeding `fscanf` a std::string.  Once you do that, then it is a purely C++ issue, as there is no such thing as `std::string` in C.  In additon, that code will not work with Visual Studio 2012 for the answers given below.  The behavior is undefined, plain and simple.  Just because it seems to work doesn't mean it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the internal buffer of an `std::string` directly as you try to do here. To read a `string`, use a stream:

```
std::ifstream in ("list.txt");
int >> currentname >> currentAge >> currentSalary;
```

If you really need to use `fscanf`, use a big enough `std::vector<char>` instead and use it like a C-style string.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` scans `%s` into a `char` array, not a `std::string`.

`std::string` is implemented with something like `struct { size_t length; char* buffer; }`, so writing into `buffer` will actually change the string. However, since it tracks its length explicitly, the `'\0'` at the end of the string won't be considered a terminator like it would in a character-array string.

You could just scan into a `char` array, but the C++ish way to do this would be to use `std::ifstream`.